How to Get Wallet Address in flutter while using web3modal_Flluter Package?
I am using web3modal_flutter package to connect meta mask and other crypto wallets to the flutter application. Problem I am facing is that I am unable to dynamically get the address of the wallet to sign in the transaction. By giving it manually(By just copying it from meta mask) it signs my transaction. But I want to take automatically take the address of the connected wallet. Is there any way to get the address of connected wallet.
I read the documentation of web3_modal but couldn't figure it out.

I used onModalConnect event handler to get it:
import 'package:web3modal_flutter/web3modal_flutter.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
...

_w3mService.onModalConnect.subscribe((ModalConnect? event) async {
  ...
  //save session data
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setString('address', event!.session.address.toString());

});

Here you can check the list of events you can subscribe:
https://docs.walletconnect.com/appkit/flutter/core/events
